# Troubleshooting with "Gambler-code"

Tags: java, gambling

I'm doing a project in school were we are supposed to sort of simulate a betting scenario, we had this code to begin with;

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/Gambler.java.html

However our task were to change this code so that for every bet that's made were supposed to print a " * " for every dollar that we have after that bet.

So for example if we win 1$ after the first bet and we start with 5$ as our stake, then the program should print 6 "*" and then do the same thing for the next bet and vice versa.

I've tried different things but can seem to get it to work properly, therefore I'm asking you guy's here for some advice/help.

This is what i've come up with so far;

```
public class GamblerStars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stake = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // gambler's stating bankroll
        int goal = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); // gambler's desired bankroll
        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); // number of trials to perform

        int bets = 0; // total number of bets made
        int wins = 0; // total number of games won

        // repeat trials times
        for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
            int cash = stake;
            int star = 0;

            while (cash > 0 && cash < goal) {
                bets++;

                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    cash++; // win $1

                    while (star <= cash) {
                        star++;
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }

                } else {
                    cash--; // lose $1

                    while (star <= cash) {
                        star--;
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            if (cash == goal)
                wins++; // did gambler go achieve desired goal?
        }
        System.out.println(wins);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your while block to this:

```
    // it's always a good idea to parametize your conditions
    while ((cash > 0) && (cash < goal)) {
        bets++;

        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            cash++; // win $1
        }
        else {    // move the else up here, so it's parallel to the win
            cash--; // lose $1
        }

        // you only need one block to print the stars, not two
        while (star <= cash) {
                star++;
                System.out.print("*");
        }

        // you don't need to use a parameter to just print a newline            
        System.out.println();
    }
```

That should at least help you spot your problem.